# How do I move an image down a couple of pixels?

Tags: css, css-float

http://jsfiddle.net/sWceL/

I am trying to horizontally center a loader gif next to a button. The only way I can figure out how to do it, is by floating the gif and moving it all over. Is there a better way?

In my example, the loader on the left is what I want, without float if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will want to use `vertical-align: middle;` without `float: left`.

Note that you will need to change the order of the elements in the HTML if you want to put the gif on the left side of the button.

Here's a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WUUtT/).

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

http://jsfiddle.net/sWceL/3/

note: leave the one loader you need